# RNN, binary classification with very different performance for each class

Tags: neural-networks, classification, accuracy, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently using an RNN for an underlying binary classification problem (0,1). When I look at the results I have one big question, why is the out of sample accuracy for class "1" much better than the accuracy for class "0"? I identify class 1 in almost 90% of the cases correctly, while class 0 is correctly classified in only 10-20% of the cases. Does anybody have an idea what induces this problem and maybe how to solve it?

Comment: I am not clear precisely what you mean by "I identify class 1 in almost 90% of the cases correctly, while class 0 is correctly classified in only 10-20% of the cases" but some adjustment to your model might be able to increase the number of correctly predicted class 0 cases, possibly at the cost of fewer correctly predicted class 1 cases.  The overall accuracy may go down

Comment: Could you elaborate what adjustments you would recommend? And what I meant was, after training, the Network did classify 90% of the 1's in the test-sample correctly while only 10-20% of the 0's in the test-sample were correctly classified.